# Threading super Class - args

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, class

I am trying to work with a thread for a logging GUI that I have pieced together from various sources.  I can get it to work if I hard code the function it calls into the run method `jnw.main()`, but any way I try to make the callable function an argument to pass to the class it I end up with different errors, depending on how I am trying to pass the argument.

I am pretty new to python and I might be in over my head a bit, but any help would be appreciated.

```
from main_log import App, logger
from tkinter import *
import logging
import jvc_network as jnw
import threading

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class ThreadLogger(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def run(self):
        print ('Run Thread')
        jnw.main()
  
    def stop(self):
        print("stopped")
        
root = Tk()
app = App(root)

logger.info('Test started')

t1 = ThreadLogger()
t1.start()

app.root.mainloop()

t1.join()
t1.stop()
print("DONE")
```

Comment: Explain "mess". What happens, what should happen (edit the question)?

Comment: Well for example if I try to pass the function using `def __init__(self, targfunc):` and try to replace `jnw.main()` with `self.targfunc()` the thread never starts, the App runs in the main thread and then I get `AttributeError: 'ThreadLogger' object has no attribute 'targfunc' `. I have tried various other ways to pass in the function I want to call and they all result in different types of errors.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and put the _minimal_ code in the reproduces the problem, a [mre], if you want any actual help.